# Bytes assigned inconsistently

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, multithreading

I have some strange behavior when trying to assign a portion of a byte array to two separate byte arrays to be sent out as serial commands on separate serial ports. I have broken up the code to be able to walk through it more easily; the problem is easily repeatable but makes no sense to me.

```
byte[] cmd1 = CLEAR_COMMAND;
byte[] cmd2 = CLEAR_COMMAND;

byte[] parameterBytesCmd1 = IntToByteArray(parameter1);
cmd1[3] = parameterBytesCmd1 [0];
cmd1[4] = parameterBytesCmd1 [1];

Thread.Sleep (100);

byte[] parameterBytesCmd2 = IntToByteArray(parameter2);
cmd2[3] = parameterBytesCmd2 [0];
cmd2[4] = parameterBytesCmd2 [1];
```

You can see I am taking a couple of integer parameters, converting them to byte arrays, then putting them into particular positions in the command template I've built. If I do this without sleeping in-between for at least 100ms, the contents of `cmd1` and `cmd2` will be identical every time -- `[3]` and `[4]` for both `cmd1` and `cmd2` will contain the data from `parameterBytesCmd1[0]` and `[1]`.

FWIW, this occurs on a separate thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem likely comes from

```
byte[] cmd1 = CLEAR_COMMAND;
byte[] cmd2 = CLEAR_COMMAND;
```

You are copying the array named `CLEAR_COMMAND` to both `cmd1` and `cmd2` and modifying its content. You need to make a copy of the array and assign it to the variables so cmd1 and cmd2 don't modify the original record and don't interact with each other.

If you add a `using System.Linq;` to the top of your file you should be able to do the following to make shallow copies of the arrays. Depending on if you want cmd1 and cmd2 to point at the same array in memory you will want to do either

```
byte[] cmd1 = CLEAR_COMMAND.ToArray();
byte[] cmd2 = CLEAR_COMMAND.ToArray();
```

or

```
byte[] cmd1 = CLEAR_COMMAND.ToArray();
byte[] cmd2 = cmd1;
```